# How to use middleware for a specific route in krakenjs?

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

In the [deploying middleware example](https://github.com/lensam69/Kraken_Example_Custom_Middleware), middleware is used with kraken like the following

```
// index.js
...
app.requestBeforeRoute = function requestBeforeRoute(server) {
  server.use(millionsServed());    
...
};
```

But this way, the middleware is applied for all routes in the app. Suppose I only want to apply it for a specific route like in express like this:

```
app.get('/user', helpers.ensureAuthenticated, userCtrl.index);
```

How can I do the same with kraken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can added in the controller, same way like the express does.

```
// controllers/index.js
module.exports = function (server) {

    server.get('/', helpers.ensureAuthenticated,  function (req, res) {
        var model = { name: 'krakene' };

        res.render('index', model);

    });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd take the same approach in kraken. You register routes in the familar, express way inside your controllers. As such, you can register route-specific middleware just the same.